# Method is expecting an iterator but receiving a list, can't resolve

Tags: c++, list, iterator, constants

One of my methods is expecting an iterator and instead is getting a list. I'm having a hard time correcting this as c++ is not a language I am overly comfortable in. I can't seem to figure out how to return a new iterator pointing to the list instead. This issue is within the begin() methods as outlined below. Rest of code provided for context.

error code --error C2440: '' : cannot convert from 'const linked_list' to 'const_square_list_iterator'

```
template <class list>
class square_list 
{
    linked_list<linked_list<list>>          _data;
    int                                     _size;
public:
    typedef list                value_t;
    typedef list&               ref_t;
    typedef list const&         const_ref_t;
    typedef list                value_compare;
    typedef square_list<list>   square_list_t;
    typedef linked_list<list>   linked_list_t;
    typedef linked_list<list> const&  const_linked_list_t;
    typedef square_list_t*      square_list_ptr_t;
    typedef linked_list_t*      linked_list_ptr_t;
    typedef node<list>          node_t;
    typedef node_t*             node_ptr_t;
    typedef square_list_iterator<list>       square_iterator_t;
    typedef const_square_list_iterator<list>         const_square_iterator_t;
    typedef square_list_iterator<list>               reverse_iterator_t;
    typedef const_square_list_iterator<list>          const_reverse_iterator_t;

private:
    std::vector<double> _alloc;
    value_compare       _comp;

public:

    square_list() : _data( linked_list<linked_list<list>>() ), _size( 0 ) {}
    square_list( square_list && sl ) {  // Rvalue move ctor
        _data = std::move(sl._data);
        _size = std::move(sl._size);
    }
    ~square_list() {}

    square_list& operator = ( square_list && sl ) { // Rvalue = operator
        _data = std::move(sl._data);
        _size = std::move(sl._size);
        return *this;
    }

    // methods
    //bool empty() { return begin() == nullptr; }
    int size() const { return _size; }

    square_iterator_t begin(){return square_iterator_t(_data);}
```

---

```
    const_square_iterator_t begin() const 
    { return const_square_iterator_t (_data); }
```

---

```
    const_square_iterator_t cbegin() const 
    { return const_square_iterator_t(_data); }

    square_iterator_t end()
    {
        square_iterator_t iter(_data);
        while(iter != nullptr) ++iter;
        return iter;
    }
    const_square_iterator_t end() const 
    {
        const_square_iterator_t iter(_data);
        while(iter != nullptr) ++iter;
        return iter;
    }
    const_square_iterator_t cend() const 
    {
        const_square_iterator_t iter(_data);
        while(iter != nullptr) ++iter;
        return iter;
    }

    reverse_iterator_t rbegin(){ return reverse_iterator_t(_data)};
    const_reverse_iterator_t rbegin() const { return const_reverse_iterator_t(_data)};
    const_reverse_iterator_t crbegin() const { return const_reverse_iterator_t(_data)};
    reverse_iterator_t rend() { 
        reverse_iterator_t iter(_data);
        while(iter != nullptr) ++iter;
        return iter;
    }
    const_reverse_iterator_t rend() const { 
        const_reverse_iterator_t iter(_data);
        while(iter != nullptr) ++iter;
        return iter;
    }
    const_reverse_iterator_t crend() const { 
        const_reverse_iterator_t iter(_data);
        while(iter != nullptr) ++iter;
        return iter;
    }
    list front();
    list back();
    void insert( list data );
    void erase( square_iterator_t& i );

    void squarify();
    void print();

    bool empty() const _NOEXCEPT{
        return _size == 0;
    }

    std::vector<double> get_allocator() const _NOEXCEPT{
        return _alloc;
    }

    value_compare value_comp() const {
        return _comp;
    }


};
```

This is the code for the const_square_list_iterator class.

```
template<class list>
class const_square_list_iterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, list, int>
{
typedef square_list<list>   square_list_t;
typedef linked_list<list>   linked_list_t;
typedef square_list_t*  square_list_ptr_t;
typedef linked_list_t*  linked_list_ptr_t;
typedef node<list>      node_t;
typedef node_t*         node_ptr_t;

node<linked_list<list>>*        _pHeadNode;
node_ptr_t                  _pNode;

public:
const_square_list_iterator() {}
const_square_list_iterator( linked_list<linked_list<list>> &data ) : _pHeadNode(data.head()) {
    if(_pHeadNode)
        _pNode = _pHeadNode->data.head();
    else
        _pNode = nullptr;
}
const_square_list_iterator( std::nullptr_t &p ) : _pHeadNode(p), _pNode(p) {}
~const_square_list_iterator() {}

node_ptr_t getNode() { return _pNode; }
node<linked_list<list>>* getHead() { return _pHeadNode; }

reference operator * () { return _pNode->data; }
const_square_list_iterator & operator ++ () { // pre
    if( _pNode ) {
        if( _pNode->next )
            _pNode = _pNode->next;
        else if( _pHeadNode->next ) {
            _pHeadNode = _pHeadNode->next;
            _pNode = _pHeadNode->data.head();
        } else
            _pNode = _pNode->next;
    }
    return *this;
}
const_square_list_iterator operator ++ (int) { const_square_list_iterator retval = *this; ++*this; return retval; } // post
bool operator < ( const_square_list_iterator const& rhs ) const { return _pNode < rhs._pNode; }
bool operator != ( const_square_list_iterator const& rhs ) const { return _pNode != rhs._pNode; }
bool operator == ( const_square_list_iterator const& rhs ) const { return _pNode == rhs._pNode; }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your begin method is const, then it is trying to pass _data as const. Your const_square_list_iterator constructor takes a non-const list, so the compile can't find a match.
Change the const_square_list_iterator constructor declarion to

```
const_square_list_iterator( const linked_list<linked_list<list>> &data )
```

Answer (score 0):

Data member _data has type

```
linked_list<linked_list<list>>          _data;
```

const_square_iterator_t is defined as

```
typedef const_square_list_iterator<list>         const_square_iterator_t;
```

And how do you expect the compiler should convert `linked_list<linked_list<list>>` to `const_square_list_iterator<list>` in function begin?

```
const_square_iterator_t begin() const 
    { return const_square_iterator_t (_data); }
```

Is any constructor of `const_square_list_iterator<list>` that has a parameter of type `linked_list<linked_list<list>>`?

Comment: One of the constructors for const_square_list_iterator is (linked_list<linked_list<list>> &data)

Comment: @user3317003 The compiler does not agree with you.

Comment: Then perhaps I've made the ctor wrong and simply can't see it anymore. I've been staring at it for the better part of 8hours now.